# form action from domain1.com to domain2.com takes long time, origin issue?

Tags: forms, server-administration

I have a simple html form that form action is **always a URL of domain1.com**, where it is processed by a php/js app.

When I put and submit the form on **domain1.com** (where it also is sent to and processed) it takes just 1 second.

When I put and submit the form on **domain2.com** (form action is still a URL on domain1.com) it takes up to ~30 seconds.

I think it is some server settings that needs to be tweaked on domain1.com that makes problems when the form is not submitted from same domain.

How can I fix this so that the form submitting in any case just takes 1 second?

[image]

Comment: Please share more details, like your debugging attempts. Also, if this is related to Javascript, PHP, or anything else, please explain how this is related

Comment: I’d start by checking the request in browser dev tools – Chrome’s “waterfall” shows the different phases, so go and figure out _which part_ takes so long first of all. https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#timing-explanation

Comment: I have added the Waterfall entry as a picture in the post above that takes so long time.
As you are asking about these information, I guess it looks as a script issue instead of a server configuration issue?